# What is the rap mechanism used in "No Pixar" called?

Tags: styles, rap

There is a mechanism / technique used in rap, I guess it's like a count, a speed, the number of words per line or something that determines how a rap is performed lyrically/rythmatically, and I listened to a certain rap which was very lyrically catchy in the speed of the words and the end rhyme which was unique from other raps I've heard.

My question is probably not put well because I'm not a musical specialist - I'm asking about a mechanism that I dont know much about, but think is probably common vocabulary for rap artists. I'm looking for the name of the lyrical mechanism/technique, or whatever you would call it, that defines the style of this song, "No Pixar".

Comment: Hello and welcome to Music.SE!  
You can click [here](http://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
to see our scope (what/what not to ask) and how to ask questions 
[here](http://music.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hip_hop_genres and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDGLDGRN. The band that does that song (from my hometown?!) is usually described as "indie go-go".

Comment: please write out a short segment of lyrics that illustrates the concept.

Comment: I agree with @dwoz

Comment: @dwoz ok this evening when I get time I will

Answer (score 2):

Had a moment to go search some lyrics for the aforementioned rap.  As far as it goes, there's not a lot of unique happening in there...it's basically rhyming couplet lines, many of the rhymes are partial or forced.

Thematically, it's right up on the surface, pretty much right down the middle of the pipe for the genre.

There's a lot of rap that does very sophisticated things with scansion, internal rhymes, acceleration of rhymes, delayed resolutions, rests, alliteration...I don't see much of that going on here.  If you're into learning about what makes a great rap, this particular rap, "no pixar" doesn't have a lot of flesh on the bones.

Comment: miaow, damn son.

Comment: strikes and balls...strikes and balls.